# exponential function of percentage add as well as static increase.

Tags: functions, exponential-function, graphing-functions

${f(x)}=100(1+0.01)^{x}$

That equation will add $1%$ every $x$ value with a starting value of $100$. However, I need it to add $10$ ever $x$ value as well. For example, at $x = 1$, $y$ should equal $111$ because added $1%$ then added $10$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, just add $+10x$ to your function

Comment: @TobiasMolenaar, it is not clear, but your suggestion of $100\times 1.01^x+10x$ would give $122.01$ when $x=2$.  Perhaps what is wanted is $1\%$ more than $111$ (i.e. $112.11$) then plus $10$ to give $122.11$.  If so, then $1100\times 1.01^x-1000$ might work better.

Comment: @Henry Thanks, Thats exactly what i needed